# Замена строк в XML c помощью регулярных выражений PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, xml, commerceml

Доброго времени суток.
Возник следующий вопрос.
Имеется XML файл, форматированный по [CommerceML 2](http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/90/92.htm).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<КоммерческаяИнформация xmlns="urn:1C.ru:commerceml_2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ВерсияСхемы="2.07" ДатаФормирования="2015-09-13T17:50:32">
    <Товары>
        <Товар>
            <!--- .. -->
            <ЗначенияСвойств>
            <!--- .. -->
                <ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <Ид>bdfe66a6-707f-11e4-bac6-50b7c36a6683</Ид>
                    <Наименование>м3</Наименование>
                    <Значение>2,25</Значение>
                </ЗначенияСвойства>
            </ЗначенияСвойств>
           <!---..-->
           <Упаковки>
                <УпаковкаТовара>
                    <Ид>bdfe66a6-707f-11e4-bac6-50b7c36a6683</Ид>
                    <Наименование>м3</Наименование>
                    <Значение>2,25</Значение>
                </УпаковкаТовара>
            </Упаковки>
        </Товар>
    </Товары>
</КоммерческаяИнформация>
```

Открываем файл, изменяем спецсимволы для упрощения работы. Потом из обработанной строки с помощью регулярных выражений необходимо получить значения упаковок товара. Составляем массив найденных значений, а потом, проходя по массиву, изменяем значения свойства, причем задаем фиксированные Ид товарам с определенным :

```
<?php

//Меняем символы < и > на &lt; и &gt;
$xml_origin = str_replace("<","&lt;",str_replace(">","&gt;",file_get_contents("import.xml"))); 

//Ищем все совпадения соответствующие паттерну
preg_match_all("/((\&lt;)УпаковкаТовара>\s*
 (\&lt;)Ид>\s*.*?(\&lt;)\/Ид>\s*
 (\&lt;)Наименование>\s*.*?(\&lt;)\/Наименование>\s*
 (\&lt;)Значение>.*?(\&lt;)\/Значение>\s*)/",
$xml_origin, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

//Составляем массив: ключ - ИД, а значение - Наименование
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $val) {
    preg_match("/(\&lt;)Ид(\&gt;)\s*.*?(\&lt;)\/Ид(\&gt;)\s*/",
        $val, $ids);
    $proc_ids[] = $ids[0];
    preg_match("/(\&lt;)Наименование(\&gt;)\s*.*?(\&lt;)\/Наименование(\&gt;)/",
        $val, $titles);
    $proc_titles[] = $titles[0];
}
$data = array_combine($proc_ids, $proc_titles);

//Формируем массив строк-замен
foreach ($data as $id => $title) {
    $search_line[] = "/((\&lt;)ЗначенияСвойства(\&gt;)\s*".trim($id)."\s*".trim($title).")/";
    if ($title == "&lt;Наименование&gt;м3&lt;/Наименование&gt;"){
         $match_line[] = "&lt;ЗначенияСвойства&gt; &lt;Ид&gt;some_id1&lt;/Ид&gt; ".trim($title);
    }
    elseif ($title == "&lt;Наименование&gt;м2&lt;/Наименование&gt;") {
         $match_line[] = "&lt;ЗначенияСвойства&gt; &lt;Ид&gt;some_id2&lt;/Ид&gt; ".trim($title);
    }
    elseif ($title == "&lt;Наименование&gt;шт&lt;/Наименование&gt;") {
         $match_line[] = "&lt;ЗначенияСвойства&gt; &lt;Ид&gt;some_id3&lt;/Ид&gt; ".trim($title);
    }
}

//Заменяем строки
$xml_processed = preg_replace($search_line,$match_line, $xml_origin);
print_r($xml_processed);
?>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что возвращается пустая страница, если попробовать вывести результат замены строк. То есть судя по документации замена preg_replace происходит с ошибкой.
Если же изменить искомые строки, на более простой и односложный паттерн
  (к примеру, "/\<ЗначенияСвойства\>/"), то тогда всё работает и строки заменяются.

То есть проблема либо в неправильной регулярке preg_replace(в конкатенации), либо в символах табуляции.

Знаю, это неправильно обрабатывать XML грубым таким проходом с помощью регулярных выражений, что нужно использовать парсеры типа SimpleXML, но в нём как-то не разобрался.

Быть может, вы мне поможете.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хватит, слышите, хватит использовать регулярные выражения для работы с XML! Используйте нормальный парсер.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML - это реально просто, и дока есть.

```
$string=<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<КоммерческаяИнформация xmlns="urn:1C.ru:commerceml_2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ВерсияСхемы="2.07" ДатаФормирования="2015-09-13T17:50:32">
<Товары>
    <Товар>
        <!--- .. -->
        <ЗначенияСвойств>
        <!--- .. -->
            <ЗначенияСвойства>
                <Ид>bdfe66a6-707f-11e4-bac6-50b7c36a6683</Ид>
                <Наименование>м3</Наименование>
                <Значение>2,25</Значение>
            </ЗначенияСвойства>
        </ЗначенияСвойств>
       <!---..-->
       <Упаковки>
            <УпаковкаТовара>
                <Ид>bdfe66a6-707f-11e4-bac6-50b7c36a6683</Ид>
                <Наименование>м3</Наименование>
                <Значение>2,25</Значение>
            </УпаковкаТовара>
        </Упаковки>
    </Товар>
</Товары>
</КоммерческаяИнформация>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

var_dump($xml);
```

Результаты:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'ВерсияСхемы' => string '2.07' (length=4)
      'ДатаФормирования' => string '2015-09-13T17:50:32' (length=19)
  public 'Товары' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public 'Товар' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
          public 'comment' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'ЗначенияСвойств' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
              ...
          public 'Упаковки' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
```

Ещё есть simple_xml_load_file и simple_xml_import_dom.

Для старта достаточно.